# access php variable through concatenation

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I was trying to achieve something simple and was wondering if it was possible. Google search proved unhelpful this time. Probably it's not possible, but I am not sure. I have the following code:

```
<?php
    //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$query1="yay";
$query2="it";
$query3="works";

for($x=1;$x<=3;$x++){
    $query="\$query".$x;  //I need to assign the above variables
    echo $query;
}

?>
```

I want the output to be "yayitworks" but instead I get "$query1$query2$query3". Is there any way to get my result? I know a switch statement will help me achieve this, but am just curious.

Thanks in advance...:-)

Comment: Remove the backslash before the dollar sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

`$query = ${"query".$x}`

Comment: omg!! First variable functions, now variable variables. Thank you for the info. I didn't know this existed...:-)

Comment: @user3889963 I made a mistake in my original answer, don't know if you tried it yet, but I just edited it to fix it, should work properly now.